# Schedule for self-replication projects for Mars?

Tags: mars

What are current known feasible plans to establish self-replicating assets on Mars?
On Wikipedia, there are references to NASA plans telling that up to 80% could be manufactured, but is there any progress in this direction?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_mining#Self-replicating_machines

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clanking_replicator#Prospects_for_implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no concrete plans for off-world self-replicating systems. NASA is [studying the idea](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?N=0&Ntk=All&Ntt=self-replicating%20system&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial) (and has been for decades), but we're too far away from any self-replicating system to start designing one for Mars.

Perhaps the group closest to achieving the goal of self-replication is the [community trying to build self-replicating 3D printers](http://www.reprap.org/wiki/RepRap), but they're not there yet (can't replicate the electronics, for example).

Comment: thank you - I think maybe there will be some intermediate solution  e.g. have a complex of machines which can together group-self-replicate more than 50% of components.

Comment: @J.Doe: Some manufacturing machinery for a colony is a given. The round-trip is too long to depend on delivery of replacement parts from Earth. This will likely not be a classic "self-replication" but a combination of machining, 3D printing and ISRU manufacture of raw materials, in major parts manual or computer-aided, not fully automatic.